# Enabling/Disabling a resource in terraform without using count

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I am trying out the conditional creation of the VPC module using `count` but when I use count , terraform fails saying `The Count value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, but resource attributes are already applied.`

CONTEXT:

I want to conditionally create a VPC based on user input , if the user passes a CIDR block the vpc module uses it other wise it has to fetch the next available CIDR  from IPAM. I have the below code

```
data "aws_vpc_ipam_pool" "ipv4_ipam_pool" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.ipam_pool_name[data.aws_region.current.name]]
  }
}

# Preview next CIDR from pool if 
resource "aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr" "previewed_cidr" {
 count   = data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_type.value =="existing" ? 0 : 1 # If the vpc_type value in SSM is existing it won't create the IPAM CIDR
  ipam_pool_id   = data.aws_vpc_ipam_pool.ipv4_ipam_pool.id
  netmask_length = var.vpc_mask_length[data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_size.value]
}

locals {
  partition                         = cidrsubnets(aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr.previewed_cidr[0].cidr, 1, 1)
  private_subnets                   = cidrsubnets(local.partition[0], 2, 2, 2)
  
  disconnected_vpc_cidr             = "10.150.0.0/22"
  disconnected_vpc_private_subnets  = ["10.150.0.0/25","10.150.0.128/25","10.150.1.0/25"]
 
}


module "vpc" {
  count   = data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_type.value == "none" ? 0 : 1
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.19.0"

  name            = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.account_alias.value}-vpc"
  cidr            = data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_type.value == "existing" ?local.disconnected_vpc_cidr : aws_vpc_ipam_preview_next_cidr.previewed_cidr[count.index].cidr  # Fetch CIDR value from locals or IPAM based on the SSM param value
  azs             = formatlist("${data.aws_region.current.name}%s", ["a", "b", "c"])
  private_subnets = data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_type.value == "disconnected" ? local.disconnected_vpc_private_subnets : local.private_subnets

  enable_nat_gateway   = false
  enable_vpn_gateway   = false
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = merge({ environment = data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value })
}
```

Is there any option in terraform that could help me get around this problem without usinf count? Any suggestions on how to refactor the logic are appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Sadly no. You have to re-architect your application to not depend on unknown data, e.g. deploy your resources in two stages. Or don't use terraform.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't that you used `count` specifically, but rather that the decision about how many instances of this module to declare is based on a result that Terraform can't known until after it has applied the plan, and so it can't produce an actionable plan for this resource. The same would be true for *any* mechanism for deciding dynamically how many instances to declare.

To make this work you will need to ensure that the decision for how many instances to declare is based only on values declared directly in your configuration, and not on anything that requires first applying a change to a remote system.

In your case there is some indirection between the cause and the effect, but the root problem seems to be that the configuration of `data aws_ssm_parameter" "vpc_type"` itself includes an unknown value, and therefore Terraform can't read that data source until the apply phase.

You've not included that block in your example so I can't guess why exactly that value wouldn't be known during planning, but if you make sure that all of the arguments in that `data` block are known during planning then Terraform will be able to read that data source during the plan phase and thus it will know the value of `data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_type.value` to compare it with `"none"` and therefore decide how many instances of `module "vpc"` are being declared.